# SQL loader error unable to open Bin folder

Tags: oracle, shell, sql-loader

I am creating a sql Loader for which i have created a control file :

```
LOAD DATA
   INFILE 'Lookup_code.csv'
   insert INTO TABLE XXHCM_LOOKUP_EXT
   (
    LOOKUP_TYPE  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) ,
    LOOKUP_CODE  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) ,
    MEANING      VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) ,
    ENABLED_FLAG VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
   )
```

I have placed it in `/orabin/hrtst/TEST` . Now when i am running the concurrent program i am getting an error :

```
Arguments
------------
/orabin/hrtst/TEST
------------
SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (/orabin/hrtst/apps/apps_st/appl/per/12.0.0/bin/Control.ctl)
SQL*Loader-553: file not found
SQL*Loader-509: System error: No such file or directory
```

When i am searching for `/orabin/hrtst/apps/apps_st/appl/per/12.0.0/bin` location to place my control file there because my current location is not getting picked. I am getting an error in WINSCP that this location does not exist. What am i doing wrong in the steps followed

Comment: What is your 'concurrent program' doing, and where does WinSCP fit in? Are you creating the control file on one PC and then trying to run SQL\*Loader somewhere else?

Comment: @AlexPoole The concurrent prog is of type SQL Loader. which means it will follow whats given in the control file and insert the data to the staging table mentioned in the control file. But the problem is that the program is not detecting the path being passed in the parameter

Comment: I know what SQL\*Loader is and how it uses control files, but you seem to have another layer of Perl script/program that you run and which calls SQL\*Loader. You are passing a path argument to Perl but you haven't shown what that is doing with it. The reference to WinSCP is confusing. Is your script supposed to transfer a file and then load it?